# I can't remove or delete a curve from an object

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

I have an object made up of a collection of curves (that I created from a mesh), and I need to move one of them into its own object so I can style it individually. Failing that, I want to delete it entirely.

[image]

Nothing I try seems to work. I've tried separating it out into a new object, but it doesn't go, and the new object is empty. I've also tried "delete segments" and "delete vertices" (I don't really know what those two options mean), but nothing changes.

Can anyone tell me the super-simple thing I need to do to separate it and/or remove it, please?

Thank you very much.

-- Dunstan

Comment: I think the problem is you are selecting only a single vertex. Under *Edit Mode* Select one single vertex from the desired Spline > Press `Ctrl+L` to select all linked vertex > Press `P` to separate whole segment. You should end up with another object that contains new spline. You can also style each separate curve individually by assigning it a separate material.

Comment: Magic, Duarte. Thank you. I didn't realize that I hadn't actually selected the "spline". So many ui cues to learn...

Comment: And thank you too, lemon. You're right, I had clicked 'Restrict viewport selection', but it didn't seem to have any effect in this case. I appreciate the reply, though.

Comment: How should I indicate that this question has been answered? I don't want to rob you of any answer-karma, Duarte.

Comment: Well, as I write this, you can't indicate the question has been answered, because the question hasn't been answered, as a consequence of the fact that @DuarteFarrajotaRamos provided the answer in a comment. If he moves the content to an answer, then you can upvote and accept the answer, to provide Duarte with his answer karma.

Comment: Haha don't worry I've had my healthy daily dosage of karma thanks. I'll post a proper answer later when I get to the computer. **EDIT**: Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are selecting only a single vertex. To separate you will need more than one vertex selected.

Under *Edit Mode* either manually select the whole spline, or only the desired segments before separating. Alternatively select only one single vertex from the Spline you wish to separate, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked vertex > Press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate whole segment.

You should now end up with another object that contains new spline.

Seeing as you already seem to have attempted separation by selecting a single vertex, you may need to do some cleanup.

Although apparently nothing happened, you probably succeeded in separating a single vertex curve object. These are very hard to select, and nearly impossible to see. In *Object Mode* either hide the larger curve objects, or use *Border Select* and *Border Deselect* to attempt to select the single-vertex curves and remove them.

On a side note, if by "styling" you simply mean assinging a different material , you can style each separate spline inside the same curve object individually by assigning it to a separate material slot, and choosing a different material for each slot.

You can also control bevel thickness on a per-vertex basis with the *Radius* property, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in *Edit Mode* for the currently selected vertex.